# libpcre2-dev dependencies unmet problem on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My problem is that I wanted to install OwnCloud on ubuntu, and long story short, I had to downgrade PHP from v8 to v7.2 and I found problems

Honestly, I don't really know the problem exactly but when I run the upgrade command, for example, I get this error

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcre2-dev : Depends: libpcre2-posix2 (= 10.39-2+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Even when I run the apt --fix-broken install command, I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libpcre2-posix3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpcre2-posix2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpcre2-posix2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,300 B of archives.
After this operation, 33.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 251030 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpcre2-posix2_10.39-2+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcre2-posix2:amd64 (10.39-2+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcre2-posix2_10.39-2+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.
org+1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-posix.so.3', which is also in package libpcre
2-posix3:amd64 10.37-0ubuntu2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcre2-posix2_10.39-2+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I want to solve this problem but most importantly, I want to learn more about Linux so any explanation is more than welcome. Thank you!

Comment: As the text says : `no longer required: libpcre2-posix3` ....... so please try removing with `sudo apt remove libpcre2-posix3`

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, but when I execute the command, the same output of the first error

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the reverse situation (posix3 instead of posix2):

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libpcre2-posix2
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpcre2-posix3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpcre2-posix3
```

This is what worked for me. (for you it would be `libpcre2-posix3`)

```
sudo dpkg --purge libpcre2-posix2
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

All good after that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked for me without upgrading/downgrading etc. +1

Comment: It worked on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Worked for Debian 11->12

Answer (score 1):

###### I had the same issue earlier when I wanted downgrade php8.0 -> php7.4.

The below commands solved the issue:

```
 srcFile="/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-impish.list"

 sed -i 's/# //g' ${srcFile}
 apt update
 apt autoclean
 apt autoremove -f -y
```

##### If everything went fine and you still need php7.2, see below:

---

1. If you are using php-gearman, you need to add ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman
2. If you are using apache2, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/apache2
3. If you are using nginx, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline

---

##### Install php7.2:

```
 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php <<< "2"
 apt install php7.2 -y
```